# How to get a large amount of records from the oracle DB using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, controller, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a large amount of records in a Oracle db and I need to get all those records in a single request.
The request in takes more than 15-20 seconds, sometimes I am getting a time out error.

Comment: how should anyone provide a **better** alternative, if we don´t even know your **bad** one? Please provide your code. Also did you use a profiler to see if the delay is really caused by the code you´re looking at? Chances are you´re losing time at a completely different location.

Comment: The default command timeout is 30 seconds.  Increase the timeout in the command.

Comment: increase the default request timeout in web.config, and use pagination always (skip and take functions), and search about tables indexing in database side